# Why does Vista SP1 UAC prompt show a different file name for my MSI installer?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-installer, uac

For my MSI installer, Vista SP1 UAC prompt shows me "5eab7.msi" for my MSI name which is clearly not my MSI file name. However the company name is correct. How to make the UAC prompt show the real name of my installer? I am using WiX, by the way.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The UAC prompt shows a temporary random Program Name for msi, can the correct name be displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315840/the-uac-prompt-shows-a-temporary-random-program-name-for-msi-can-the-correct-na)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the UAC prompt shows you the file name of the temporary msi object the msiexec creates.

If you want to avoid having shown that msi, you can sign your msi and provide a description when signing it (the '/d' switch in signtool). Then the UAC will show that description instead of the temp file name.