# Program name in a "User Account Control" prompt

Tags: wpf, installation, wix, uac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The UAC prompt shows a temporary random Program Name for msi, can the correct name be displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315840/the-uac-prompt-shows-a-temporary-random-program-name-for-msi-can-the-correct-na)

On installing my WPF application, in a ***User Account Control*** prompt, asking *"Do you want to allow the following program to install software on this computer?"*, **Program name** is shown something like **1054504.msi** (digits can be different on various computers).

**What should I do to show a meaningful name in this field?**

(Installer package is created using WiX. Product *Id* and *Name* are defined.
AssemblyInfo's *AssemblyProduct* is defined as well.)

**EDIT:**

I've found the solution in [this another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315840/the-uac-prompt-shows-a-temporary-random-program-name-for-msi-can-the-correct-na). I tried and it perfectly worked.
So my question can be closed.