# Code signed MSI name issue, WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer, code-signing, digital-signature

I coded my [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) installer using [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX). The MSI is also signed with my code signing certificate. When I begin its installation I get the following security warning on Windows 7:

[image]

But for some reason the *Program Name* is nothing but the name of my MSI or anything I added to it.

Is there a way to give it some user-friendly name to display in that warning?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The UAC prompt shows a temporary random Program Name for msi, can the correct name be displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315840/the-uac-prompt-shows-a-temporary-random-program-name-for-msi-can-the-correct-na)

Comment: @MichielB: Good job! 5 yrs later, but you got it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With SignTool.exe it is enough to set a description text from what I remember, this being used as application name in the UAC prompt. Have you tried that? (don't know if this is supported from WiX)

Comment: Oops. You're right, dude. This has nothing to do with WiX. I forgot to add `/d Desc` parameter for SignTool.exe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz.aspx Thanks!