# How to set the program name of the security box from an MSI setup?

Tags: security, wix, windows-installer, uac

I have create a signed MSI installer with the WIX toolset. The setup show a security box before installing (not on start). This security box show a cryptic name of hex numbers because the MSI file was copied to the C:\windows\installer directory.

Is there an option to show a nice program name in this security box?

Here is a sample of such security box:

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315840/the-uac-prompt-shows-a-temporary-random-program-name-for-msi-can-the-correct-na

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using the signtool.exe to sign your installer, use the `/d` option to provide a description text. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to [Authenticode-sign your .msi](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/Ee290833%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to control the UAC prompt.

Comment: This I have already signed the msi file. But the program name is cryptic.

Comment: That's not what I get on Windows 8.1. Can you add a screen shot?

Comment: @BobAmson I have add a screen shot to the question.