# Change publisher name for Setup Project visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer, publisher

How do I change the publisher name for the visual studio installer in visual studio 2015?
I want to be able to display the correct publisher name in Programs and features section of control panel when its install.

Comment: u sure setup project is still supported in VS2015? pretty sure they dropped it long time ago

Comment: Are you using the VS2015 Installer Project extension?

Comment: @stuartd yes, I am. Should I be using some a different package?

Comment: @Steve what do you recommend I should use then?

Comment: @callme_wiz you need to ask google and pick one that's suitable for you. there is no universal answer to that.

Comment: I use that package to support installer projects for an old customer support contract. You can certainly set the `Manufacturer` property and some other properties like URLs. Not sure about Publisher though.

Comment: OK thanks, I will check and see if the Manufacturer Name will display when the project is being installed @stuartd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Manufacturer Property***: I only have access to the 2017 version. However, in Visual Studio, when you left click the installer project in "*Solution Explorer*", is there not a properties list that includes the property "Manufacturer"? Please try to change the name there.

[image: Ze Company]

***UAC Prompt***: In order to change the name which shows up in the UAC pop-up dialog to elevate rights for the installation, you need to sign your package with an appropriate certificate. [Is it possible to define a Windows Installer-uninstaller filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079546/is-it-possible-to-define-a-windows-installer-uninstaller-filename) (also check the links).

> ***UPDATE***: Even signed MSI packages can show up with a dodgy name in the UAC prompt. [Here is a description of how to avoid this by
>   proper signing procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58154444/129130).

[image: UAC]

---

***Some Links***:

- [How to add publisher in Installshield 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407893/how-to-add-publisher-in-installshield-2018)
- [Installshield Custom Dialogue Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204163/installshield-custom-dialogue-installer) (screen shot of non-signed MSI UAC dialog)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) to create an MSI.
After successfully configuring and creating the MSI package, I follow these steps:

1. In their organization, they receive an internal certificate with a private key that allows me to sign the private key
2. Export it to pfx format
3. I sign my MSI package

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce\SignTool>signtool.exe
> sign /f "C:\Users\kul\source\repos\kul.pfx" /p
> "mypass" /d "SuperSoft"
> "C:\Users\kul\source\repos\SuperSoft\Release\Setup.msi"

[image]