# Where does signtool.exe store the application name when signing an .MSI file?

Tags: uac, signtool, authenticode

We're having the following situation.
An .MSI file, after being signed using signtool.exe, will show the following UAC prompt:
[image]

The same .MSI file, after being signed with a custom tool that uses the CryptUIWizDigitalSign API, shows the following UAC prompt:
[image]

We want to make sure the .MSI file displays the "Our awesome application" text in the UAC prompt, not some id generated by the MSI engine.

We've tried filling the field `pwszDescription` in the [`CRYPTUI_WIZ_DIGITAL_SIGN_EXTENDED_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/cryptuiapi/ns-cryptuiapi-_cryptui_wiz_digital_sign_extended_info) structure:

> A pointer to a null-terminated Unicode string that contains the description of the subject of the signature.

but this did not work.

Is there another field we can use for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The UAC prompt shows a temporary random Program Name for msi, can the correct name be displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315840/the-uac-prompt-shows-a-temporary-random-program-name-for-msi-can-the-correct-na)

Comment: It is not a duplicate question, the guy was using signtool.exe, while we're using a custom tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end filling the pwszDescription field worked fine, I can only assume we were making some other error.